# Get the main where of query

Tags: java, regex

I want to get the index of main where clause of database query in Java ? 
How can I handle this with Regex?

For example in this query I want to get Second where clause:

```
  select u.id, (select x.id from XEntity where x.id = 200) 
  from UserEntity u 
  **where** u.id in (select g.id from AnotherEntity g where g.id = 100)
```

I think the main where is which that number of "(" characters and ")" characters is equal after it.
but I don't know how can I get this with regex.

With Best Regards

Comment: Use regular expressions for recognizing WORDS, not STRUCTURES: http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/do_NOT_parse_using_regexp.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Toote and David Brabant said is absolutely correct. Parsing SQL, especially complex SQL using only regex is a very hard problem.

In terms of parsing SQL in Java, which seems to be the thrust of your question, there's a very good (if apparently un-maintained) library [called JSQLParser](http://jsqlparser.sourceforge.net/). A more up-to-date version of this library can be found on Github [here](https://github.com/wumpz/JSqlParser) (disclaimer: I made a very small contribution to this). The main page shows an example of visitor designed to consume the output of the AST [here](http://jsqlparser.sourceforge.net/example.php).

There is also a grammar for ANTLR [available in it's grammar list](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list). Or, if you're feeling adventurous, the H2 database supports a rather extensive range of SQL, including some proprietary features of, e.g., MySQL. You could modify it's [Parser](https://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/main/org/h2/command/Parser.java) to generate an appropriate structure for extracting the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expressions are not very good at recognizing such complex structures as SQL queries can be. Mainly because SQL is not context-free, which is exactly the issue you are running into: the WHERE can appear in a lot of places and you want one in particular that depends on the overall structure of the query.

What you will need is an appropriate parser. The [only JavaScript SQL parser I could find](https://github.com/forward/sql-parser) is not too complete, but you can always help develop it by making sure it fits your needs.